# Why is `android ServerSocket().accept().getInputStream().read()` so slow?

Tags: android, performance, inputstream, serversocket

The same file, the same operation (client), submitted to the php service, received and saved it only takes 500 milliseconds, submitted to Android, received and saved but takes 50 seconds.

#### tips

android avd : android tv api 25
android avd port forward: `android/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:11111 tcp:11111`
client is chrome : `http://php.local.qidizi.com/i.php?html=1`
There are only two files for this test, `MainActivity.java` and `i.php`.

### file content

#### MainActivity.java

```java
package qidizi.t.myapplication;

import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final static int PORT = 11111;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        create_httpd();
    }

    private void debug(String msg) {
        Log.d("qidizi_debug", msg);
    }

    private void create_httpd() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ServerSocket httpd;
                try {
                    // 使用端口转发功能,把虚拟机avd端口转发到开发机的11111上,就可以使用 http://127.0.0.1:11111 来访问
                    // android/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:11111 tcp:11111
                    httpd = new ServerSocket(PORT, 1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    debug("httpd-fail:" + e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                debug("httpd running");
                //noinspection
                while (true) {
                    long accept_a = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    debug("accept waiting " + accept_a);
                    debug(
                            "RELEASE " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE
                                    + ",model " + android.os.Build.MODEL
                                    + ",dev " + Build.DEVICE
                                    + ",brand " + android.os.Build.BRAND
                                    + ",board " + Build.BOARD
                                    + ",MANUFACTURER " + Build.MANUFACTURER
                    );
                    try (
                            Socket client = httpd.accept();
                            InputStream is = client.getInputStream()
                    ) {
                        Log.d("qidizi_debug", "accept receive " + accept_a + ",cost " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - accept_a));
                        long while_a = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        try {
                            // get 支持的长度
                            int mark, index = 0, max_head = 1024;
                            int[] ints = new int[max_head];
                            int rn_rn = 0;

                            // 读取文件头时,使用单个byte读取
                            while (true) {
                                mark = is.read();

                                if (mark < 0)
                                    throw new Exception("http head error");

                                if (index + 1 > max_head)
                                    throw new Exception("http head too big");

                                ints[index] = mark;
                                index++;

                                if ('\n' == mark || '\r' == mark) {
                                    rn_rn++;
                                    if (4 == rn_rn) {
                                        // 找到head与body分隔
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    rn_rn = 0;
                                }
                            }

                            // 取首行
                            String head = new String(ints, 0, index).toLowerCase();
                            //noinspection UnusedAssignment
                            ints = null;
                            int body_size = 0;
                            String len_str = "content-length: ";
                            int len_a = head.indexOf(len_str);

                            if (len_a > -1) {
                                len_a += len_str.length();
                                // 不含数字前空格和后面换行符号
                                body_size = Integer.parseInt(
                                        head.substring(len_a, head.indexOf('\r', len_a)), 10
                                );
                            }

                            debug("body size: " + body_size + ",read head cost " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - while_a));
                            if (head.startsWith("options /"))
                                debug("allow");
                            else if (head.startsWith("post /apk?"))
                                install_apk(is, body_size);
                            else
                                throw new Exception("action now support:" + head);
                            debug("process cost: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - while_a));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            debug("error: " + e.getMessage());
                        } finally {
                            String body = "ok";
                            client.getOutputStream().write((
                                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                                            + "Allow: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS\r\n"
                                            + "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n"
                                            + "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"
                                            + "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *\r\n"
                                            + "Content-Length: " + body.getBytes().length + "\r\n"
                                            + "Connection: Close\r\n"
                                            + "\r\n"
                                            + body
                            ).getBytes());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        debug("new socket fail:" + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("qidizi_debug", "while end,cost " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - accept_a));
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


    private void install_apk(InputStream is, int body_size) throws Exception {
        // 上传文件
        if (body_size < 1024)
            throw new Exception("apk body < 1024");

        if (null == is)
            throw new Exception("http inputStream null");

        long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String apk_path = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp.apk";

        File file = new File(apk_path);

        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            int mark;

            long size = body_size, while_a = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    loop_a = System.currentTimeMillis(), tip_times = 500000;
            while (size > 0 && -1 != (mark = is.read())) {
                // is.read() never return -1 ,don't use   -1 != (mark = is.read()) && size > 0
                out.write(mark);
                --size;

                if (0 == size % tip_times) {
                    debug(is.available() + " available,read " + tip_times + " (size = " + size + "),cost "
                            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - loop_a));
                    loop_a = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
            debug("read body cost: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - while_a));

            if (0 != size)
                throw new Exception("http body broken,body-content-size " + body_size + ",only get " + size + "(" + (size * 1.0 / body_size) + "%)");

            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("save fail:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        long body_time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - a) / 1000;
        debug("upload success " + body_time + " s");
    }
}
```

#### i.php

```php
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['html'])) {
    ?>
    use php <input type="checkbox" id="php"><br>
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <input type="button" onclick="upload()" value="upload">
    <div id="tip"></div>
    <script>
        function ajax(data) {
            let time_a = +new Date;
            let done = false;
            let xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && !done) {
                    done = true;
                    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = xhr.response + '<br>js cost ' + (+new Date - time_a) / 1000;
                }
            };
            xhr.onabort = xhr.onerror = function () {
                if (!done) {
                    done = true;
                    alert("connect fail:" + xhr.statusText + '[' + xhr.status + ']');
                }
            };
            let url = 'http://';
            url += document.getElementById('php').checked ? 'php.local.qidizi.com/i.php?' : '127.0.0.1:11111/apk';
            url += '?r=' + +new Date;
            xhr.onloadend = function () {
                document.title = 'end';
            };
            document.title = 'request ...';
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                document.title = 'upload ' + (e.loaded / e.total).toFixed(2) * 100 + '%';
            })
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.send(data);
        }

        function upload() {
            let self = this;
            let file = document.getElementById('file').files;

            if (!file.length) {
                alert('select file');
                return;
            }

            file = file[0];

            if (!/.apk$/i.test(file.name)) {
                alert('only apk');
                return;
            }

            let max_mb = 200;
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * max_mb) {
                alert('must < ' + max_mb + 'MB');
                return;
            }

            ajax(file);
        }

    </script>
    <?php
    exit;
}

$input_size = file_put_contents('a.apk', file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo 'input size ' . $input_size . '<br>';
echo 'a.apk size ' . filesize('a.apk') . '<br>';
```

### post to php service, fast, only 500ms;

[image]

### post to android java service , very slow, 59s

[image]

### logcat log

```
D/qidizi_debug: httpd running
    accept waiting 1595654479838
    RELEASE 7.1.1,model sdk_google_atv_x86,dev generic_x86,brand generic_x86,board unknown,MANUFACTURER unknown
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8c1270c0, tid 12435
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8c127500, tid 12451
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x985c00e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x985c00e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9858df80)
I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x985c00e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9858df80)
D/qidizi_debug: accept receive 1595654479838,cost 116751
D/qidizi_debug: body size: 0,read head cost 4
    allow
    process cost: 4
D/qidizi_debug: while end,cost 116757
    accept waiting 1595654596595
    RELEASE 7.1.1,model sdk_google_atv_x86,dev generic_x86,brand generic_x86,board unknown,MANUFACTURER unknown
D/qidizi_debug: accept receive 1595654596595,cost 4
D/qidizi_debug: body size: 6382654,read head cost 5
D/qidizi_debug: 912340 available,read 500000 (size = 6000000),cost 3559
D/qidizi_debug: 941588 available,read 500000 (size = 5500000),cost 4533
D/qidizi_debug: 908948 available,read 500000 (size = 5000000),cost 4571
D/qidizi_debug: 896344 available,read 500000 (size = 4500000),cost 4912
D/qidizi_debug: 948440 available,read 500000 (size = 4000000),cost 4837
D/qidizi_debug: 914712 available,read 500000 (size = 3500000),cost 4630
D/qidizi_debug: 927004 available,read 500000 (size = 3000000),cost 4598
D/qidizi_debug: 896732 available,read 500000 (size = 2500000),cost 4566
D/qidizi_debug: 912480 available,read 500000 (size = 2000000),cost 4539
D/qidizi_debug: 935904 available,read 500000 (size = 1500000),cost 4548
D/qidizi_debug: 902496 available,read 500000 (size = 1000000),cost 4679
D/qidizi_debug: 500000 available,read 500000 (size = 500000),cost 4686
D/qidizi_debug: 0 available,read 500000 (size = 0),cost 4529
D/qidizi_debug: read body cost: 59189
D/qidizi_debug: upload success 59 s
    process cost: 59199
D/qidizi_debug: while end,cost 59205
    accept waiting 1595654655800
    RELEASE 7.1.1,model sdk_google_atv_x86,dev generic_x86,brand generic_x86,board unknown,MANUFACTURER unknown
```

why?
How to fix it if only use `int i = InputSream.read()`(no `BufferedInputStream`)?
thank you!

Comment: `(mark = is.read()))` You read one byte at a time. That takes much too long. Declare a byte buffer of say 8192 and then read in the buffer like `nread=is.read(buffer);`.

Comment: @blackapps   Thank you, I understand the need for other methods, just to make sure it's really so slow? Now it seems that it is really so slow.But I still don't know why it's so slow?

Comment: That i already told you. Because: `You read one byte at a time. That takes much too long.`. And in the loop -so for every byte- you do all kind of time consuming things.

Comment: @blackapps  I mistakenly thought it was as fast as the code below.` int i = 1024*1024*6;
        byte[] a = new byte[i];
        byte[] b = new byte[i];
        long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (i-- >0) a[i]=b[i];
        debug("cost " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - s));`, result `cost 75`; But finding out it's not what I want to do like this.thank you!